# Selecting Data from Compressed TEXT Column in Sybase

Tags: sybase

In Sybase 15.03 we have a table with column named "content" type TEXT.
It contains compressed contents of the file, looks something like this when doing straight select:
H4sIAAAAAAAAAL2Y21IjOQyG7/cp+nJny9UjWbIszx2QQDIJhMmhanff/0H2d6cpSOKh2ZoMQFWS

How can I select/extract/uncompress/decompress its value, so I can examine its content?

Thank you.
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a SELECT of the column, and make sure the SET TEXTSIZE setting is set high enough to avoid the data being truncated. 
To get the data in a file directly, do a BCP-out (and use the -T flag similarly to SET TEXTSIZE).

Comment: I think the issue is COMPRESSED nature of text column content. Simply increasing TEXTSIZE has not helped.

Comment: As far as ASE is concerned, a TEXT or IMAGE column is just a string of bytes. ASE just stores and retrieves the data, it's up to the application to interpret what's stored in there.